# How to add resource parameter to acquireTokenSilent method of an msal instance in Angular?

Tags: angular, access-token, azure-ad-msal

```
const tokenRequest = {
  scopes: [''],
};

token = await this.msalService.instance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
```

I want to pass the client Id of my Web API as a resource paramater while generating the access token. Unable to figure out how to do so..

Answer (score 0):

You do not rely on the resource parameter, you rely on the scopes.

MSAL uses the v2.0 endpoints of AAD, so your permissions needs to be passed inside the scopes array.

Assuming you are using MSAL v2, this will use the Authorization Code with PKCE flow, and you can check it below how the scopes are used by MSAL behind the scenes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

To have a real world example, check this official MS sample, with an Angular frontend calling a custom .NET Core API. It uses an Interceptor to handle the token acquisition for you, but you can take look:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api

If you really want to acquire tokens explicitly from the msal instance, then you can see here how it can be done:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript2